# Can I use a 3.5 A charger for a 2.0 A spec’d notebook?

Tags: laptop, charger

As per specifications, my MSI notebook requires a 20 V / 2.0 A charger. Unfortunately, they are hard to find.

Can I use a 20 V / 3.5 A charger without damaging my notebook?

Comment: -1 for not googling- can i use higher amp charger/power supply

Comment: @barlop If you’re unhappy with my revision, feel free to improve it. I think it’s better than a situation where answering “yes” would mean the exact opposite in title and text.

Comment: @DanielB I have no opinion on how the question looked before, or how it looks now. I'm not big on grammar so can't comment on that. But I found the question easy to understand before and after.

Comment: Actually, I'd argue that the linked-as-duplicate question is about a different situation, as it asks whether a *different voltage* power supply can be used. Admittedly in the case of the duplicate target the voltage difference is small, but it is still a different situation than where the two power supplies involved have the same specified output voltage. Voting to reopen this question.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, the charger rated for a higher amperage will work fine with your laptop.**

Using a higher amperage, *same voltage, same polarity* charger does not pose a problem. The computer (or anything else) will simply draw as much as it needs and not more.

You should be careful though to check polarity; some are center pin negative, and others are center pin positive. Bad things almost certainly *will* happen if you get this wrong, and it won't be related to the amperage at all. And of course a different voltage charger could easily cause problems, depending on the exact voltage difference and exactly how the computer is built.

Compare this to the electrical wiring in your house; it's likely that the fuses are rated for a load of 2-3 kW or more (in my part of the world, fuses for 10 A 240 V = 2.4 kW are common, and the main service fuses are often 16 A or higher), yet that light bulb of at most a few tens of watts works just fine. Your computer is not really different, except it probably runs on DC which means you have to pay attention to polarity.

Comment: The comparison to the light bulb is pretty good, it makes for a good simple example

Comment: @DaveRook I thought myself that it would be enlightening (pun intended).